# How to create quick-entry dialog with system-wide shortcut?

Tags: macos

I really like how [Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) gives us ability to capture todos without switching to the app. How to do this? I can't find any relevant code with google. Any ideas, urls or maybe code snippets?

Comment: You can either build another program as a helper, which runs in the background waiting for a global shortcut to be called and which communicates with the main program afterwards (this is the way Things is doing it). Or you can design a quick entry window within your application and start it when an global shortcut was called. The second solution will only work if your main program is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned about global hotkeys from the example on this website [here](http://dbachrach.com/blog/2005/11/program-global-hotkeys-in-cocoa-easily/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with *Things*, but it sounds like you're describing a [Service](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html). Services live in the application menu under Services.

TextEdit.app provides a "New Window Using Selection" service, for example.

Comment: No it's not a service, but a helper which runs in the background. If you open the activity monitor and filter for the term `Thins` you will see two applications: `Things` and `Things Helper`.